# Mongoose Regexp Research

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I'm trying to search in mongoose using `$regex` but it doesn't seem to be working when I use an integer.  I am not getting any record even when I search with an existing data.  What am I doing wrong?

Code snippet:

```
    exports.getprofilesbyfirstname = function (req, res) {
        var params = req.params;
        var record = db.collection('profile');

        console.log(params.id);

        record.find({
           phone: { 
             $regex: params.id,
           },
        }).toArray((err, result) => {
           if (err) return console.log(err);

           if (result) response = {status:'success',data:result};
           else response = {status:'fail',data:[]};

          res.send(response);
       });
   };
```

Comment: Can you give to us the entry of `firstname` you added and an example of `params.id` please?

Comment: Ohh i am so sorry Gregory,its a phone not firstname....i edited my code ..please check

Comment: try `{ $regex: new RegExp(params.id) }` please

Comment: Thanks it wrked finnaly

Answer (score 0):

When you use **static** regex, use the flat regex syntax:

```
{
   $regex: /peter/i
}
```

When you want to use a **dynamic** regex (use of **variables**), use the *RegExp class* syntax:

```
{
   $regex: new RegExp(data, 'i'),
}
```